# How can I change the font color of link text using inline CSS?

Tags: css, html

I added an "aside" to the essay "To the Person Sitting in Darkness" [here](http://twaincentral.azurewebsites.net/) (Miscellaneous tab), but the links appear ghostlike. What inline CSS do I need to add to make those links dark (forestgreen would work, probably)?

Comment: What does "ghostlike" mean? Got a picture?

Comment: Where on the page are we supposed to be looking?

Comment: Go to the link and select the "Miscellaneous" tab, and you'll see what I mean (it appears to be dark grey against a black background).

Comment: The aside at the very top of "To the Person Sitting in Darkness" (right beneath that title).

Comment: `<a ... style="color:mediumseagreen "`>. You sure you want inline?

Comment: How come can that be a "correct" answer when is implying bad practices ehic is inline styling, if you take a look at my answer will see that I found your issue and gave it a good solution

Comment: Because it worked. It's just one page; using an inline solution will not cause the cities to crumble in ruins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `a` link, right after the `a`, add `style="color:green"` Substitute "green" for any HEX color you want.

Answer (score 3):

You could manually add **"style: color #FFF8DC;"** to each of the  tags in the aside elements

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippine%E2%80%93American_War" target="_blank" style="color: #FFF8DC;">The Philippine-American War</a>
```

The more efficient way is to add this style to the *stylesheet*, not inline on each element.

```
.aside a {
    color: #FFF8DC;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that your [jqueryUI.css](http://twaincentral.azurewebsites.net/css/excite-bike/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css) file is applying a darker gray here in line 413:

```css
.ui-widget-content a {
  color: #222222;
}
```

if you remove this line you'll get the `a` to its normal color style which is `#333`, applied in [your CSS file](http://twaincentral.azurewebsites.net/Content/Site.css?v=77) line 476.

```css
a {
  color: #333;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

if you want a different color to that links specifically then you just need to set this in your CSS:

```css
#MiscTwainContent a {
   color:#whatevercoloryouwant
}
```

**With this in mind, no need for using inline-styling, which it is not a good practice.**

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it, since the question is just asking about the link text (inside an a / anchor tag) is this:

```
a {
  color: green;
}
```

Or better yet, per'aps:

```
a:link, a:visited {
  color: green;
}
```